# Display datetime like 1 hour ago, 5 hours ago - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am display last login time on my control panel. How do I display datetime like this:

```
1 hour ago, 
5 hours ago
```

Comment: Here's some javascript based answers: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641791/javascript-library-for-human-friendly-relative-date-formatting 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: Take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moment.js is definitely a great way to do this. I've set up a Plunkr for you which shows a basic example on how you could do this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/64mfpDhUxdXcQo6r8Xrf?p=preview

To summarise, you can use the `.fromNow()` method to display the difference between your date and the current time:

```
$scope.difference = moment($scope.yourDate).fromNow();
```

If `$scope.yourDate` is from 1 hour ago, `$scope.difference` will be set to `an hour ago`.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I've update the Plunker to use the date you've provided.

```
$scope.yourDate = new Date('2015-07-08T14:02:42.973');
$scope.difference = moment($scope.yourDate).fromNow();
```

At the time of writing, this sets `$scope.difference` to `20 hours ago`.

Comment: Hi @uikrosoft. I've updated my answer to use this date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular-timeago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-timeago) to achieve that.

Once installing the package, you will need to reference it in the `angular.module` as per the following.

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', ['yaru22.angular-timeago']);
```

Then you can use inline pipes to cast any date value into "ago" string
e.g.

```
{{myDate | timeAgo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this here is a simple package [ngx-pretty-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pretty-date) that provides a simple date pipe.

Once you install the package just import it into your `app.modules.ts`

```
import { NgxPrettyDateModule } from 'ngx-pretty-date';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxPrettyDateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then use it in your components

```
<span> {{dateObj | prettyDate}} </span>
```