# Current time will display,next day same time will converted to date like month and date using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want output like below image I showed,first current time will display, next day that time will converted to date, exactly I want output below I showed image.

[image: after]

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">                                       
   <?php echo date("F j ", strtotime($row->msg_sent_time)); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: [With JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7641791/1267304)

Comment: with or without js i need output as i shown in image

Comment: Did you checked the link ?

Comment: without js how to do

Comment: You can transcribe the snippet in the link i've posted to php, it is just simple as a half hour job.

Comment: i cannot understand what your saying

Comment: My last comment is well translated in translate.google.com to my native language, I'm not sure for indian tho... but, I'm saying that you can get the JS code from the link I have posted and re-write it in PHP as it is very trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145969/discussion-between-siddu-m-and-dontvotemedown).