# How to convert today date numeric to string today's

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, salesforce, lwc

I would like to show today instead of not showing Date(23-07-2020) in numeric values. Is it possible?

Like this picture I need to show the date as today or yesterday

[image]

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = String(today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate());
var time = today.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
this.dateTimeValue = dateTime;
```

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat

Comment: @KrutiChoksiPatel that link _is this_ question...

Comment: It has many solutions I guess

Comment: I didn't get solution has you mention link , there is any need to modify the code were I mentioned

Comment: Wheather is need to change the code, can you please help me @evolutionxbox.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to achieve it:-

1. By using some library such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)
2. Or by using the native methods and writing the logic for all calcualtios.

**1st approach**:-

If you want to go with the first approach you can find the link [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

you can use the functions *toNow()* or *fromNow()* depending upon the requirement
Here as per your question *fromNow()* is suitable

Here is the link code Pen [link](https://codepen.io/shankar1011/pen/GRoepZb?editors=1111)

and below is the code snippet:-

```
let date = moment("2020-07-23", "YYYY-MM-DD");
document.write(date.fromNow());
```

which is using momentjs library

**2nd approach**:-

A **similar question** can be find [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641791/javascript-library-for-human-friendly-relative-date-formatting)

*for which the code pen link is here* [code pen](https://codepen.io/shankar1011/pen/RwrdWLX)

Comment: The stand INTL object does it for us. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat

Comment: it will be pleasure to me if you edit the answer and provide the link :) thank you @evolutionxbox

Comment: I’m happy for you to put it in the question, or we could leave the link as a comment. :)

Comment: I don't understand the link as you have given @evolutionbox , can you explain me

Comment: hey @CibiSaranSivaprakasam please check the code pen link mentioned in the answer. Hope that will help :)

Comment: Thank for your answer, I asked in dynamic way to convert date in numeric to string as today.as you mentioned in that codepen we manually giving date change as today but I should be dynamic @shankarupadhyay