# Javascript given month return the time string

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a JS library/utility/function where you give it num of month and it returns the human readable version of it.

I have almost done it in Vanilla JS but now I figure out there are a lot of edge cases that I do not want to ***re-invent the wheel***.

Example

```js
func(3) => "3 Months"
func(1) => "1 Month" // singular
func(0.1) => "1 Week"
func(0.25) => "2 Weeks"
func(13) => "1 year and 1 month"
func(14) => "1 year and 2 months"
func(14.25) => "1 year, 2 months and two weeks"
.
..
...etc
```

Problem Statement: I don't want to re-invent the wheel and see if there are any library that is currently doing date conversion as above.

Comment: Please share as what you have tried and what issues are being faced?

Comment: Please provide what is the problem and what you have tried till now

Comment: @cauchy added the problem statement

Comment: There's a special word for such libraries. Humanizer. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641791/javascript-library-for-human-friendly-relative-date-formatting

Comment: The `Date` constructor is simple to use, why not just use that?

Comment: @StackSlave because Date constructor creates the number of month from now....

Answer (score 1):

Using the `moment.js`:

```js
Date.getFormattedDateDiff = function (date1, date2) {
  var b = moment(date1),
    a = moment(date2),
    intervals = ['year', 'month', 'week', 'day'],
    out = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    var diff = a.diff(b, intervals[i]);
    b.add(diff, intervals[i]);
    if (diff == 0)
      continue;
    out.push(diff + ' ' + intervals[i] + (diff > 1 ? "s" : ""));
  }
  return out.join(', ');
};

function OutputMonths(months) {
  var newYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  var days = (months % 1) * 30.4167;

  var newDate = new Date(newYear.getTime());
  newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + months);
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);

  console.log('Number of months: ' + Date.getFormattedDateDiff(newYear, newDate));
}

OutputMonths(3);
OutputMonths(1);
OutputMonths(0.1);
OutputMonths(0.25);
OutputMonths(13);
OutputMonths(14);
OutputMonths(14.25);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your version of a 'human readable version' is. You could simply convert your month number to days and work from there. Since you included years, months and weeks in your example cases all you'd need is this.

```js
function func(months) {
    let days = months * 30.5; // Average days in a month
    let y = 0, m = 0, w = 0;
    while (days >= 365) {y++;days -= 365;}
    while (days >= 30.5) {m++;days -= 30.5;}
    while (days >= 7) {w++;days -= 7;}
    let out = 
        (y ? (`${y} Year` + (y > 1 ? "s " : " ")) : "") +
        (m ? (`${m} Month` + (m > 1 ? "s " : " ")) : "") +
        (w ? (`${w} Week` + (w > 1 ? "s " : " ")) : "");
    console.log(out);
}
func(10);
func(3);
func(1);
func(0.1);
func(0.25);
func(13);
func(14);
func(14.25);
```

***Simpler is always better***, specially when it's such a simple problem. You don't want to bloat your application with a library just for this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(moment.duration(40, 'months').toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[image: momentjs duration use]

Have a look at https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range also